# public static HashSet<string> thread safe?

Tags: c#

Basically i have an app calling 3 different threads that each that a new HashSet and I want to know is this thread safe?  or do I need a [ThreadStatic] added to each hashset?

Answer (score 6):

If you instantiate three different `HashSet`s, and each `HashSet` is accessed only by a single thread, then it will be fine. You only need to add the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute if there is a single static `HashSet` shared among threads.

**[Update]** Just to clarify how `[ThreadStatic]` would work.

Disclaimer: I **never** use `[ThreadStatic]`. The presence of that attribute has a lot of consequences which are not obvious and are hard to debug (as well as test properly) IMO.

Let's say you really want to use `[ThreadStatic]` in a test class:

```
public class ThreadStaticTest
{
    // CLR ensures that each thread accessing this field
    // gets a separate instance of the *field*. This, however,
    // means that static initializers don't work. Field is
    // null at first access from an individual thread
    [ThreadStatic]
    static HashSet<string> _hashset;

    // This is why we instantiate it explicitly here:
    private HashSet<string> HashSet
    {
        get
        {
            _hashset = _hashset ?? new HashSet<string>();
            return _hashset;
        }
    }

    public void AddItem(string s)
    {
        // thread safe
        HashSet.Add(s);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetItems()
    {
        // thread safe
        return HashSet;
    }
}
```

Running the following console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // single test instance!
    var test = new ThreadStaticTest();

    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        threads.Add(new Thread(() =>
        {
            var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            test.AddItem("Hello from thread #" + threadId);
            Console.WriteLine("Instance contains {0} items: '{1}'", 
                test.GetItems().Count(), 
                string.Join(", ", test.GetItems().ToArray()));
        }));
    }
    threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
    threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());

    Console.Read();
}
```

Shows that, although there is a single test instance, each thread gets a new instance of the hashset:

```
Instance contains 1 items: 'Hello from thread #11'
Instance contains 1 items: 'Hello from thread #13'
Instance contains 1 items: 'Hello from thread #10'
Instance contains 1 items: 'Hello from thread #12'
Instance contains 1 items: 'Hello from thread #14'
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right.  "Indicates that the value of a static field is unique for each thread."  So no data sharing is possible between threads.  i.e. 3 threads == three static instances.

Comment: @sgtz is correct. `[ThreadStatic]` will not cause the HashSet to magically be thread safe, it will just present a different storage location for each thread that accesses that static field. @Mike: you need to synchronize access to the `HashSet` yourself, or use a free-threaded collection such as `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: @sgtz: I am not sure what you mean by "no data sharing is possible between threads". It isn't, in two cases: 1. if you have a single **instance** per thread or 2. if it's a **static** field mark with `[ThreadStatic]`. I don't understand what part you believe is wrong.  @Allon: OP didn't want a single HashSet to be "magically" thread-safe, he asked if three separate HashSets, each accessed by a different thread, would need to be marked with `[ThreadStatic]`. The answer is **no**, unless the HashSet is a static field accessible by all threads at the same time (which is not the case).

Comment: @Groo: My issue is with the second sentence in your answer - if there is a single static `HashSet` then adding `[ThreadStatic]` will make it so there are three storage locations each containing the same reference to that single `HashSet`, which is not thread-safe. Also, note that the OP said 'to each hashset', implying there is more than one property/field.

Comment: @Allon: I will update my answer. I am still not sure what you mean by "each containing the same reference". There **is** the problem that static initializers don't work when `[ThreadStatic]` is used, but that only means that it will have a default value.

Comment: @Groo: The case I was thinking of when reading the second sentence of your answer is if you create an object then pass it to multiple threads that store it in a `[ThreadStatic]` field, each will have its own storage but they'll all point to the same object, defeating the purpose of `[ThreadStatic]`. But you've clarified your answer, so it doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 4):

According to the MSDN docs for `HashSet`:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.